# Inserting a MySQL result-set, retrieved from a select query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, database-optimization

I've got a `MySQL` database located on **server x** and another on **server y**.

I'm trying to get the records from a table called **testx** which is located on server x, and `INSERT` them into a table called **testy**. So what I did was executed a `SELECT` statement and stored it into a `resultset`. Then I'm trying to iterate the `INSERT` statement within the `resultset` `while` loop. This is my sample code:

```
private static void cloneTableAndAlter() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InterruptedException {
        Connection connForSource = getConnectionForSource();
        Connection connForTarget = getConnectionForTarget();

        if (connForSource != null && connForTarget != null) {
            try {
                Statement st = connForSource.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                        java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

                String selectStatement = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM dbx.testx where time between ('2016-09-01 00:00:00') and ('2016-09-03 23:59:59');";

                String insertStatement = "INSERT INTO testy(" + "field1," + "field2)" + 
                        "VALUES(?,?) " +
                        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1 = VALUES(field1);"; <----field1 is a unique key but not primary

                st.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

                ResultSet resultSetForSelect = st.executeQuery(selectStatement);
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connForTarget.prepareStatement(insertStatement);
                int count = 0;
                while (resultSetForSelect.next()) {
                    ++count;
                    TableDetails tableDetails = setTableDetails(resultSetForSelect); <--- i'm getting the value from the resultset and setting it to my DTO class.
                    getTableDetails(preparedStatement, tableDetails); <--- setting the values back during the insert from the DTO
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println(count + "rows affected");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**NOTE**: The source table(**testx**) has more than a million records.

I'm able to do the insertion, but then I feel like the insertion is kinda slow where I'm getting 45-50 insertions per second. Where am I going laggy?

Is there any way that I could optimize this operation and increase the inserts or is this the nature of inserting a large data set?

Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by measuring what takes time. Is it the read, or the writes, or both. If the read is slow, maybe you just need an index on the time column. If the write is slow, you could use batching to send batches of inserts instead of doing one insert at a time. If both, maybe the network is the problem.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, noted. What does "just need an index on the time column" mean?

Comment: Your qquery looks for rows in the testx table that have a time between rwo values. If you have no database index defined on that time column, that will fore MySQL to make a full table scan to find the rows that you're looking for. If you have an index defined, it can use that index to find the rows faster.

Answer (score 0):

you can do on a other way:

**Create a Select with this Concats**

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(" ('",field1,"','",field2,"')")) as vals
from my_table;
```

The Result look like this:

**Result**

```
mysql> select GROUP_CONCAT(
    -> CONCAT(" ('",field1,"','",field2,"')")) as vals
    -> from my_table;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| vals                                                                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  ('O1','AC'), ('O1','PT'), ('O2','PT'), ('O3','MI'), ('O3','PT'), ('O4','EG'), ('O4','PT'), ('O5','PT') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

and the you can direct concat this in the insert statement and you only read one row and only write and execute one statement.

**your Code**

```
    String selectStatement = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(" ('",field1,"','",field2,"')")) as vals
         FROM dbx.testx where time between ('2016-09-01 00:00:00') and ('2016-09-03 23:59:59');";

    ResultSet resultSetForSelect = st.executeQuery(selectStatement);


    String insertStatement = "INSERT INTO testy(" + "field1," + "field2)" + 
                            + String from result +
                            "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1 = VALUES(field1);"; <----field1 is a unique key but not primary


# execute one time
```

Comment: If there are thousands of rows to insert, the string will be much too large, and the query will be, too. Not to mention that if any of the values contain a single quote, the query will be invalid.

Comment: but this is the main problem. you have to much insert call. reduce them. get 16 or 32 at one time and generate a second prepared statement with this num of value pairs